# 2 keys to a value in dictionary typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a dictionary which will show result based on the key value. I would like to read the 2 keys and show the result based on the 2 key values.
currently x['1'] = 2. The result I would like to have x['a']['1'] = 2.

```
dict: { [letters: string] : resultmodel;} = {};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after this syntax `x['a']['1'] = 2`, then it would be a dictionary within a dictionary, like this:

```
const dict: { [key: string]: { [key]: any } } = {
    ['a']: { ['b']: 'test' }
};
console.log(dict['a']['b']);
```

But you can also create a dictionary with a composite key so that your syntax would be `dict['a', 'b']`, and it would look like this:

```
const dict2: { [key1: string, key2: string]: any } = {
    ['a', 'b']: 'test'
};
console.log(dict2['a','b']);
```